# filter with req.query and I had : "error_message": "Key \"name\" required but not present." in POSTMAN

Tags: javascript, node.js

Hello I had this error since yesterday and I coudn't solve it ! I did not know the problem where :
the error : "error_message": "Key "name" required but not present." in POSTMAN
the code :

// ```   routes :

```
app.get('/v1/sites/:site_id/balise',
blueprintValidator.uriValidator,
baliseController.getByBaliseName.bind(baliseController),
sendJSON
```

)```
// balise-controller :

````
  const baliseName = req.query.name
  console.log(baliseName)
  try {
    const balise = await Balise.getByName(baliseName)

    if (!balise) {
      return next(new ResourceNotFoundError(req, res, 'No balise found for this name.'))
    }
    res.locals.data = balise
    next()
  } catch (next) {

  }
}```

// balise - model : 


```Balise.getByName = async function (baliseName) {
  console.log('aabbab')
  return await new Balise({ name: baliseName }).fetch()
}```

// balise - doc file : 

## Filter balises [/v1/sites/{site_id}/balise{?name}]

+ Parameters
  + site_id: `` (integer) ... id of the Site
  + name: `` (string)

### balise [GET]

+ Response 200 (application/json)

  JSON representation of Balise Collection Resource. The Balise resources in collections are embedded.

  + Body

            
                {
                  "id": 2,
                  "equipment_id": 1,
                  "name": "Balise2",
                  "operating_mode": "IN",
                  "power_ble": 40,
                  "latitude": 45.718416666667,
                  "longitude": 5.0804166666667
                }
````

Comment: in routes you wrote `baliseController.getByBaliseName` and in balise-controller you wrote `Balise.getByName` is that correct?

Comment: yes it is correct , balise.getByName is a function from balise - model , you can see it